# Attempting to continue my list import, instead it over overwrites my previous import in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've borrowed some code from a post on this site already and made my own. However I'm running into a problem where the multiple files in my folder path are importing OVER the previous import instead of below the created list.

What I'm trying to achieve is importing data from multiple files in a specific folder location. After pursing through each file, the next import data should be placed under the previous import data in the worksheet.

Any insights on how to fix?

Thanks so much!

cwegz

```
Option Explicit

Const FOLDER_PATH = "Test Folder Path/"  'REMEMBER END BACKSLASH


Sub ImportWorksheets()
   '=============================================
   'Process all Excel files in specified folder
   '=============================================
   Dim sFile As String           'file to process
   Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
   Dim wbSource As Workbook
   Dim wsSource As Worksheet
   Dim rowTarget As Long         'output row

   rowTarget = 2

   'check the folder exists
   If Not FileFolderExists(FOLDER_PATH) Then
      MsgBox "Specified folder does not exist, exiting!"
      Exit Sub
   End If

   'reset application settings in event of error
   On Error GoTo errHandler
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'set up the target worksheet
   Set wsTarget = Sheet1

   'loop through the Excel files in the folder
   sFile = Dir(FOLDER_PATH & "*.xls*")
   Do Until sFile = ""

      'open the source file and set the source worksheet - ASSUMED WORKSHEET(1)
      Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER_PATH & sFile)
      Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1) 'EDIT IF NECESSARY

      'import the data
      With wsTarget
         .Columns("A").Value = wsSource.Columns("A").Value 'this one works
         .Columns("B").Value = wsSource.Columns("C").Value 'this one works


         '.Range("A1" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Columns("A").Value
         '.Range("B1" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Columns("C").Value


         'optional source filename in the last column
         .Range("N" & rowTarget).Value = sFile
      End With

      'close the source workbook, increment the output row and get the next file
      wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
      rowTarget = rowTarget + 1
      sFile = Dir()
   Loop

errHandler:
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   'tidy up
   Set wsSource = Nothing
   Set wbSource = Nothing
   Set wsTarget = Nothing
   Set Selection = Nothing

    Sheets("Pull").Select
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="@", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

        Set Selection = Nothing

    Sheets("Pull").Select
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :=";", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

        Set Selection = Nothing

    Sheets("WhiteList").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("K1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="@", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

        Set Selection = Nothing



    Sheets("Summary").Select


End Sub
```

Comment: Do the source files contain multiple rows of data?  Is the data arranged in a table form with headers in row 1 or some other layout?

Comment: When you are importing the data, you're just replacing the entire column.  Instead, look in to creating a new range/finding the last cell in a range. Then offset one row.

Comment: The source files contain multiple rows and are formatted as a table with headers in row 1. @TimWilliams

Comment: @BruceWayne okay thank you, frankly I'm quite new to coding. Would you have any quick suggestions on how to write it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach, which should work if your data tables are consistent and contain no blank rows/columns.

```
Option Explicit

Const FOLDER_PATH = "Test Folder Path\"  'REMEMBER END BACKSLASH

Sub ImportWorksheets()

   Dim sFile As String           'file to process
   Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
   Dim wbSource As Workbook
   Dim wsSource As Worksheet, rngData As Range, numRows As Long
   Dim rowTarget As Long         'output row

   If Not FileFolderExists(FOLDER_PATH) Then
      MsgBox "Specified folder does not exist, exiting!"
      Exit Sub
   End If

   On Error GoTo errHandler
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   Set wsTarget = Sheet1

   'get first empty row, assuming colA always has values
   rowTarget = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

   sFile = Dir(FOLDER_PATH & "*.xls*")
   Do Until sFile = ""

      Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER_PATH & sFile)
      Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1)

      Set rngData = wsSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion '<< assumes no empty rows/columns in your data table
      numRows = rngData.Rows.Count                     '<<

      With wsTarget
         .Cells(rowTarget, "A").Resize(numRows, 1).Value = rngData.Columns(1).Value
         .Cells(rowTarget, "B").Resize(numRows, 1).Value = rngData.Columns(3).Value
         'etc etc
         .Cells(rowTarget, "N").Value = sFile 'optional source filename in the last column
      End With

      wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
      rowTarget = rowTarget + numRows   '<<
      sFile = Dir()
   Loop

    'snipped....

End Sub
```